# BeautifulSoup doesn't work

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to the web scraping.BeautifulSoup doesn't give me anything.It's strange.PS I used the "html.parser" to replace the "lxml" that also doesn't work.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
>>> bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())

Warning (from warnings module):

File"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 181
    markup_type=markup_type))
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best 
available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a 
problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different 
virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 1 of the file <string>. To get 
rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")

>>> bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"lxml")
>>> print(bsObj.h1)
None
>>> bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
>>> print(bsObj.h1)
None
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was calling `read()` repeatedly. After the first one returned the expected content, the next ones were just returning an empty [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object.

You can simply call `read()` once and store the return value in the variable and reuse it however you like, by creating multiple soup objects, etc.

```
>>> html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html").read()
>>> bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
>>> bsObj.h1
<h1>An Interesting Title</h1>
```

If you don't want to download any additional parsers the above code will also work with `html.parser`.

Answer (score 0):

When the warning appears,i just ignore it and then print bsObj.It worked.